# Palindromes and Arrays, an effort in frustration

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, palindrome

I am currently attempting to make a Palindrome Checker using a series of Clean and dirty arrays and while I've gotten it to compile but I'm having issues getting the code to detect the actual palindromes

Below is the code in question, any and all help would be most appreciated.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class palindrome
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File inputFile = new File ("Palindromes.txt");

        Scanner inputScan = new Scanner (inputFile);

        String [] dirty = new String [20];

        int i = 0;

        while (inputScan.hasNext())
        {
            dirty[i] = inputScan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(dirty[i]);
            i++;
        }
        inputScan.close();
        String [] clean = new String [i];
        String reverse ="";
        for (int x = 0; x < clean.length; x++)
        {
            clean[x] = "";
            for (int z = length; z < dirty[x].length(); z--)
            {               
                char test = dirty[x].charAt(z);
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(test))
                {
                    test = Character.toLowerCase(test);
                    clean [x] += test;
                    if (clean[x].equals(clean[z]))
                    {
                        System.out.println(clean[z] +" is a palindrome");
                    } else
                    {
                        System.out.println(clean[z] +" is NOT a palindrome");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < clean.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(clean[j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Write a method to test for the palindromic property. And your current approach seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        s = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[\\s\\p{Punct}]", "");
        int len = s.length(), mid = len / 2;
        for (int x = 0; x < mid; x++)
            if (s.charAt(x) != s.charAt(len - x - 1))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File inputFile = new File("Palindromes.txt");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile)) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = scanner.nextLine();
                if (isPalindrome(s)) {
                    System.out.println(s + " is a palindrome");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(s + " is NOT a palindrome");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for, however I am required to separate the file input into two separate arrays; one "Dirty" array that simply reads in the code from the file as it is and one "Clean" array that removes any punctuation, spacing and case sensitivity. is there any way we can implement those arrays into this code?

Comment: @MaxGrant I edited the answer to remove all punctuation, spacing, and case sensitivity from the strings.